# Best way to enter a distributed network at the socket level

Tags: filesystems, distributed, distributed-computing, distributed-system

In a distributed node network what's the best way for a node to enter the network? We're trying to make a distributed file system that's resilient to censorship.

The two ways I could think of were

1>caching ip addresses of other nodes in the network and hoping one could bootstrap our node back into the network

2> having a broadcast IP address that all of the nodes listen too.  However, this could be blocked by a firewall.

Are there any other other ways?

Answer (score 0):

May be [gossip protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gossip_protocol) could work for you:

- The core of the protocol involves periodic, pairwise, inter-process interactions.
- The information exchanged during these interactions is of bounded size.
- When agents interact, the state of at least one agent changes to reflect the state of the other.
- Reliable communication is not assumed.
- The frequency of the interactions is low compared to typical message latencies so that the protocol costs are negligible.
- There is some form of randomness in the peer selection. Peers might be selected from the full set of nodes or from a smaller set of neighbors.

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic bootstrapping problem: who do you connect to? Who do you connect to determine who to connect to? (This applies to using a Gossip protocol as well: how do you initially know who to gossip to?)

Down at the very bottom you eventually get to a seed-node list: a hard-coded list of servers that tell you who to connect to or to whom you initially connect. (Note: DNS is one way of implementing a seed-node list.)

On top of that, it depends on the nature of your distributed system. In my distributed system, I've piggybacked on top of the protocols used within the system itself. For the core, I use seed-nodes & gossip; for the next level I use seed-nodes & reliable broadcast; above that I use seed-nodes + distributed state-machine.